# Logic error in NQueens recursion program

Tags: java, function, methods, recursion

I'm using java and am trying to make a program that uses recursion to solve the NQueens puzzle. The problem is it is giving me true when it shouldn't be (for example 3 should return false because you can NQueen a 3x3 grid). I have looked through everything multiple times but I cannot find where things go wrong. Anyone have any idea?

```
package model;

public class NQueensModel 
{
    private int myNumsQueen;
    private boolean[][] myBoard;
    private static NQueensModel myModel = new NQueensModel(3);

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        System.out.println(myModel.solvePuzzle());


    }
    public NQueensModel(int nQueens)
    {
        myNumsQueen = nQueens;

        myBoard = new boolean[myNumsQueen][myNumsQueen];
    }
    public boolean solvePuzzle()
    {
        return this.solvePuzzle(myNumsQueen);
    }
    private boolean solvePuzzle(int ncolumn)
    {
        if(ncolumn>myNumsQueen)
        {
            return true;
        }
        int i;
        for( i =0; i<myBoard.length;i++)
        {
            if(this.isSafeMove(i, ncolumn)==true)
            {

                myBoard[i][ncolumn-1]=true;
                if(this.solvePuzzle(ncolumn+1)==true)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                myBoard[i][ncolumn]=false;
            }

        }
        return false;

    }
    private boolean isSafeMove(int row, int col)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<myBoard[row].length; i++)
        {
            if(myBoard[row][i]==true)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<myBoard.length; i++)
        {

            if(myBoard[i][col-1]==true)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if(this.checkLowerDiag(row, col)==true)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(this.checkUpperDiag(row, col)==true)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(this.checkLeft(row,col)==true)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }


    }
    private boolean checkUpperDiag(int row, int col)
    {   
        if(row==0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(col==myBoard[0].length)
        {
            if (myBoard[row-1][col-2]==true)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }


        else if(myBoard[row-1][col-2]==true || myBoard[row-1][col]==true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    private boolean checkLowerDiag(int row, int col)
    {

        if(col==1 && myBoard[row][col]==true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(col == myBoard[0].length)
        {
            if(myBoard[row+1][col-2]==true)
            {

                 return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if(row == myBoard.length)
        {
            return true;
        }

        else if(myBoard[row+1][col-2]==true || myBoard[row+1][col]==true)
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    private boolean checkLeft(int row, int col)
    {
        if(myBoard[row][col-1]==true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    private boolean placeQueen(int row, int col)
    {
        myBoard[row][col] = true;
        return true;
    }
    private boolean removeQueen(int row, int col)
    {
        myBoard[row][col] = false;
        return false;
    }
//  public String toString()
//  {
//      
//  }
}
```

Comment: @user2864740 CodeReview is for peer reviewing *working code*. Fixing bugs and finding errors is StackOverflow's ground...

Comment: @retailcoder I don't really find "general program logic errors" on topic .. much less when scrolling is required.